# SQLAlchemy Error when filtering

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm using using SQLAlchemy to fiter but getting an error:

```
user = session.query.filter(User.id == 99).one()


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'filter'
```

Does someone know how to filter because on [SQLAlchemy Page](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_7/orm/tutorial.html#returning-lists-and-scalars), I saw this:

```
query = session.query(User).filter
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`query` is a function, you need to pass in the `User` class to call it:

```
user = session.query(User).filter(User.id == 99).one()
                    ^^^^^^
```

SQLAlchemy cannot divine from the filter alone what type of object you want returned otherwise.

Comment: yeps, this is what I'm doing, user = session.query.filter(User.id == 99).one()

Comment: @Noor: see my answer, you are *not* doing what my answer tells you to do.